# Which statistical test to use for Experimental vs Control at multiple time points

Tags: anova, mice

my study design is as follows: Mice received a cranial trauma and post trauma were administered either active agent (experimental group) or placebo (control group). There were xxx separate groups that were euthanized at different time points:

Day 1 Group (tested pre-trauma and at day 1)

Day 3 Group (tested pre-trauma and at days 1, 3)

Day 7 Group (tested pre-trauma and at days 1,3,7)

Day 14 Group (tested pre-trauma and at days 1,3,7,14)

Day 28 Group (tested pre-trauma and at day 1,3,7,14,28)

Each of those groups consisted of 18 animals, 9 being in the control group, the other ones being in the experimental group.

I am using GraphPad Prism and my idea was to put the data into a spread sheet and run a repeated measures two way ANOVA. However, as at each time point 18 animals are euthanized, there is no further data for them at later time points and prism says

"Because some values are missing, these data were analyzed by fitting a mixed model, rather than by repeated measures ANOVA (which can't handle missing values)."

Hence, is it possible to just run an ordinary two-way ANOVA and perform Sidak test afterward?

I feel a little bit lost here. Thank you for your help!

Cheers,
Jannis

Comment: Well... this is not good. You just turned this into survival analysis, which complicates things well beyond ANOVAs.